# Convert 7 or 8 digit number to true date

Tags: date, google-sheets, date-conversion

I have a column full of dates in this format mmddyyyy and I was wondering if I could parse or convert it to mm/dd/yyyy. I tried selecting the entire row and then clicking on format -> number -> date but when I do this, a date such as 12082016 becomes 6/7/34979 which of course makes no sense at all. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit:

```
Examples:

 7072016   12/11/2021
 1202017    12/2/2017
10042016    10/4/2016
 9212016    8/12/2023
```

I changed the B to F as that is where the date column is. What is strange is that some of the values are correct

```
=date(right(B2, 4), left(B2, 2), mid(B2, 3, 2))
```

Comment: In excel use text-to-columns, fixed width, MDY, finish. Don't think google-sheets' text-to-columns works like that though.

Comment: Can you use a 'helper' column with `=date(right(B2, 4), left(B2, 2), mid(B2, 3, 2))` ?

Comment: This seems to be working a bit actually, format is correct but the actual date is wrong. Any more info on how to set this up correctly?

Comment: How is the date incorrect? Can you post some more examples of the data you have?

Comment: Done! I just edited the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to account for both 7 and 8 digit numbers. Apparently, you lost some leading zeroes when importing your data.

```
=date(right(right("0"&A2, 8), 4), left(right("0"&A2, 8), 2), mid(right("0"&A2, 8), 3, 2))
' or,
=--replace(replace(right("0"&A2, 8), 5, 0, "/"), 3, 0, "/")
```

Format the cells as `mm/dd/yyy` or however you wish; They are true dates now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Google Sheets, you'll need to format the column with the number in it as `00000000` to ensure there are a full 8 digits, including leading zeroes for months less than 10.  To do this, highlight the column with the MMDDYYYY numbers then from the *Format* menu, select *Number* then *Custom Number Format*:

[image: The Custom Number Format option on the Google Sheets Format Menu]

Then, in the dialog box that comes up, enter `00000000` (eight zeroes) and click **Apply**:

[image: Google Sheets' Custom Number Format Dialog]

Your data will be reformatted and your dates should be correct:

[image: The resulting dates are correct when the MMDDYYYY numbers are zero-filled.]

Hope this helps!

Comment: So google-sheet's worksheet functions work on the displayed (formatted) number, not the raw underlying number. Huh. Did not know that. Neat trick! +1

Comment: Excel does not work on the formatted number -- in which case your answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Date & Time values are basically series of digits, that's why it always converts it to either Date or Time, for which is formatted. 
Bttr use Custom Format,, or Change the Default as u need. 
If you want to convert any numbers into date,, 
First write 1st date of the year convert it into number,, get the Trend,, write nXt values,, & convert into an appropriate format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula using regular expressions:

`=TEXT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A1,"00000000"),"(\d{2})+(\d{2})+(\d{4})","$1/$2/$3"),"m/d/yyyy")`

Change `m/d/yyyy` to any date format you need.